# TThread Doesn't Do It's Job Unless there is a MessageBox in the Middle !

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7, tthread

i created a class of TThread to do some socket operations, the thing is, the code doesnt work unless i add MessageBox to it, sockets wont work unless i put a MessageBox call before it

```
 Sleep(2000); //Waiting for the Socket to Come to the Array
 // Messagebox(0, '', '', 0); { Wont work unless this line is Uncommented }
 if Server.ClientList[Handle] <> nil then
 begin
  if (Server.ClientList[Handle].Connected) and (AppSocket.Connected) do
  begin
   // Send Data on Socket
   // Relay Data between Server.ClientList[Handle] and AppSocket;
  end;
```

Comment: I think the call to `messagebox` serializes the thread with the main UI thread. And this is the reason it seems to be 'required'.

Comment: What type is `Server`? (ie: what components are you using for the "socket" operations)? Is the posted code part of your `TTread.Execute`?

Comment: @Johan, [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) is a Windows API, I doubt it cares much about the VCL thread.

Comment: @Cosmin, isn't MessageBox an application modal dialog, and therefore stalls the main thread requiring the VCL thread to serialized? Or am I delusional?

Comment: @Johan, it's modal relative to the thread that calls it. [Here's a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bm5kDun2) with a small console application showing different threads can "pop" there own `MessageBox`, no synchronization takes places. Besides, it'd be mighty difficult for a Windows API to synchronize with the main VCL thread, because synchronizing is a cooperative deal.

Comment: MY thinking is that the TCP comms probably needs a message queue to be processed, and the MessageBox is providing that function.

Comment: @mj2008, I also thought of that, but it's bizarre: `MessageBox` would surely pump messages while it's displaying, but once that's over, no more messages are pumped because the OP didn't mention implementing a message pump. Maybe enough messages make it through while the box is on screen to create the illusion that things are working *after* the call, but in fact all that's available is data that made it trough while the message was on screen.

Comment: Who on earth thought it was a good idea to stop us using multiple @usernames in comments?!  Stack Overflow used to be in the business of making it easy for us to communicate.  Very bad decision.  Somebody think of the users!

Comment: @killercode does your thread pump the message queue?

Comment: @David, didn't I just say `MessageBox` would pump messages while it's displaying?

Comment: @Cosmin Yes, but perhaps pumping whilst the MessageBox is showing is enough. That's my point.

Comment: Definitely a message pump issue; impossible to tell more without seeing more of the code.

Comment: @David, I got it, I write way too long comments, and nobody reads them. Because I also said that: "Maybe enough messages make it through while the box is on screen to create the illusion that things are working after the call"

Comment: @Cosmin Sorry, my mistake. Skim reading again.

Comment: As well as the inadvisability of using a Windows message-based TCP system in a secondary thread as highlighted by the other posters, this line is also somewhat worrying : 'Sleep(2000); //Waiting for the Socket to Come to the Array'.  It may well be fine, but what is happening while the thread is dead for two secs?

Comment: @David, from the time Stack Overflow started notifying people mentioned in comments, it has always only notified the first person. Subsequent "@" mentions were never effective, so the [recent change](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-use-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings-in-comments/2615#2615) makes sure people don't get the wrong idea about who will really be notified.

Comment: @rob thanks for that. I can't understand why they don't let us use multiple names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using non-blocking sockets, then your thread needs a running message queue and processing loop.  That is why calling `MessageBox()` works - it is a modal dialog that pumps the calling thread's message queue internally.  Your thread needs to call `PeekMessage()` or `GetMessage()` in a loop for the lifetime of the connection(s).  Your loop can use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` to detect when the message queue has something to process, if your thread has other things it needs to do.

Comment: i called GetMessage(), TranslateMessage() then DisposeMessage in a Row, but that didnt fix it (i called it once though, at the same place i called MessageBox API)

Comment: Calling it only once is not enough. Like I said, you need to continuously pump the queue for new messages for the entire lifetime of the connections that the thread manages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace Messagebox() with Application.ProcessMessages and see what happens.